# Different variables of recursive function in python

Tags: python

I want to compare the difference between variables in two recursive function in python.
The first is:

```
def helper(nums, target, count):
    print(count)
    if target < 0:
        return 
    elif target == 0:
        count += 1    
    else:
        for i in range(0, len(nums)):
            helper(nums, target-nums[i], count)
count = 0
helper([1, 2, 3], 4, count)
```

The count variable is always 0.

The second is:

```
def helper(nums, target, path, res):
    print(res)
    if target < 0:
        return 
    elif target == 0:
        res.append(path)    
    else:
        for i in range(0, len(nums)):
            helper(nums, target-nums[i], path + [nums[i]], res)
path = []
res = []
helper([1, 2, 3], 4, path, res)
```

The res will keep changing.

Can anyone tell me why count variable always equals 0?

Is there difference between integer variable and list variable in recursive function in python?

Comment: Reading up on [the difference between variables and objects](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) will help you understand and avoid these kinds of problems. (It might not completely resolve things, if you're confused about more than that, but it'll help.)

Comment: `res` *doesn't* change in your second example, for the same reason that `count` doesn't change in the first - it remains exactly the same list throughout the execution.  Its *contents* are modified, an option that simply doesn't exist for integers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first `helper`, `count` is a local variable.  Any changes within a particular call are lost when helper returns.  Perhaps you want `global count` at the top of helper.

In the second `helper`, `res` is also a local name, but instead rebinding a new object to the local name, the code mutates the list object, and the new addition does not go away.